# Angular Fromly - reusable custom validators

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I've managed to get the custom validators in Formly to work as per the example given in the example here: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/validators

In that example, the ip address is validated in the formly object. The function

```
{
        key: 'ip',
        type: 'customInput',
        validators: {
          ipAddress: {
            expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
              var value = modelValue || viewValue;
              return /(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/.test(value);
            },
            message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid IP Address"'
          }
},
```

The validator works for the specific field as it should. But how do I re-use this validator on other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your validator in a variable because it is simple object:

```
var ipAddressValidator = 
  {
    expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
      var value = modelValue || viewValue;
      return /(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/.test(value);
    },
    message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid IP Address"'
  };

...

{
  key: 'ip',
  type: 'customInput',
  validators: {
    ipAddress: ipAddressValidator
  },
  ...
  key: 'ip2',
  type: 'customInput2',
  validators: {
    ipAddress: ipAddressValidator
  },
  ...
}
```

Also you can make even a factory which generates a validator according to some settings. For example:

```
function getIpValidator (fieldName) {
  return {
           expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
             var value = modelValue || viewValue;
             return /(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/.test(value);
           },
           message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid '+fieldName+' Address"'
         };
}

...

{
  key: 'ip',
  type: 'customInput',
  validators: {
    ipAddress: getIpValidator("Primary IP")
  },
  ...
  key: 'ip2',
  type: 'customInput2',
  validators: {
    ipAddress: ipAddressValidator("Secondary IP")
  },
  ...
}
```